# Make an reader app full-screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Hello I have an app with a view controller where i display some text - it also have a toolbar and a navigation bar.

I want when i press a button to hide both the navbar and toolbar also the status bar and make the view with text go fullscreen and if the user taps the view the navbar and toolbar to show.

So how do I do that? i have tried playing with the frame property of the view, with no success.

EDIT here is my code right now. My issue is only 1 - the status bar is not filled - it's just a black thingy.

```
- (IBAction)goFullScreen:(id)sender {
    self.isFullScreenOn = !self.isFullScreenOn;
    if (self.isFullScreenOn) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    }else{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        self.toolbar.hidden = YES;
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -60, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 60);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially let the bar be not hidden

```
self.currentView.toolBar.hidden=NO;
```

Now to make it appear and disappear in single tap on screen,add a tapgesture recognizer in viewcontroller

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
    [self.currentView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [tapGesture release];
```

Now define handleTapGesture function as

```
-(void) handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

     if(self.currentView.toolBar.alpha==1.0 ){

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    self.currentView.toolBar.alpha = 0.0;
    //similarly add other properties to be hidden like label,button etc
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
else{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    self.currentView.toolBar.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationFade]; 

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: Still the status bar is just a black rectangle

Comment: it should be autoresized when you execute above the code, try removing your frame code.

Comment: It seems that your code has reverse logic. when isFullScreenOn, you should hide the things and you are doing reverse

Answer (score 1):

To Hide navigation bar : -

```
            self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES ;
```

To Hide status bar: -

```
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Set `hidden` property of tool bar

Answer (score 0):

Set the `hidden` properties of your navigation bar and toolbar to `YES`.

Answer (score 0):

You can show a new Viewcontroller with presentModalViewController.
You can simply dismiss it again and don't have to do any rezising.